# TabLayout and Viewpager is not working correctly with additional cutom made tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have 1 Activity with 2 custom made Tabs(Tab A and Tab B). When user clicks on either one of the Tabs, the text color will change to white color

Under Tab A ,its a tablayout with viewpager(3 tabs -> Tab1,Tab2,Tab3)

Under Tab B, its a normal content with just a textview.

When the apps run, it will launch Tab A first, when user click Tab B, it will navigate to Tab B. **The problem comes when user click on Tab A.**

**Scenario 1 - We cannot see the content in viewpager after navigating from Tab B to Tab A.**

**Scenario 2 - It cannot back to the original state where it was.**

Please refer to screenshot for a clearer explanation.

[image]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

View get_tab_a;
View get_tab_b;
TextView get_text_a;
TextView get_text_b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    get_tab_a=findViewById(R.id.view_a);
    get_tab_b=findViewById(R.id.view_b);
    get_text_a=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_a);
    get_text_b=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.tab_b);
    get_tab_a.setOnClickListener(this);
    get_tab_b.setOnClickListener(this);

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    tab_a Tab_A=new tab_a();
    get_text_a.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container,Tab_A); // when the activity started, launch Fragment_one
    transaction.commit();

}

public void onClick(View v) {

    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();

    switch (v.getId()){

        case R.id.view_a: // when user click on the 1st tab.
            get_text_a.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            get_text_b.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            tab_a Tab_A=new tab_a();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container,Tab_A);
            break;

        case R.id.view_b: // when user click on the 2nd tab.
            get_text_a.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            get_text_b.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            tab_b Tab_B=new tab_b();
            transaction.replace(R.id.container,Tab_B);
            break;
    }
    transaction.commit();
}
}
```

**tab_a.java**

```
public class tab_a extends Fragment {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_a,container,false);

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    mViewPager = (ViewPager)rootView.findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.TabLayout);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

    return rootView;
}

public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new fg1();
            case 1:
                return new fg2();
            case 2:
                return new fg3();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "Tab 1";
            case 1:
                return "Tab 2";
            case 2:
                return "Tab 3";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.misc.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#5194ff"
    android:id="@+id/container"></LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="#b2b2b2">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/view_a">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Tab A"
            android:id="@+id/tab_a"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/view_b">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Tab B"
            android:id="@+id/tab_b"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_tab_a.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.example.misc.MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/TabLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="#4052b5"
    app:tabTextColor="@color/nava_text"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/nava_text"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    android:focusable="true" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/TabLayout"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use nested fragments! You should use child fragment manager.

Try use this:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

instead:

```
mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
```

Comment: thx. It manages to settle Scenario 1 . But Scenario 2 problem still exists. Any solution for that?

Comment: getChildFragmentManager() not working for acitivity. PlZ suggest How to solve this in a appcompactActivity